# Only displaying the last record from the database using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The code is only displaying the last record from the database. What do I do to get it to display all the records from the database. I'm trying this by using nodeJS. Thank you

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();

var data;
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'root',
   password : '',
   database : 'music'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * FROM artist', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if(err) throw err;

    data = JSON.stringify(rows);

    for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
        data = rows[i].artist_name + " "+rows[i].artist_id;
});
connection.end();

app.get("/artists", function(req,res){
    res.send(data);
})

var myServer = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on port 3000");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning your data value to each row in the for loop; that is, every iteration of the loop, you *replace* the value. Instead of using the assignment operator (=) use a contaminator (+=):

```
var data = "";
var rowDelimiter = "<br>"; // Or whatever you want
```

And then:

```
data += rows[i].artist_name + " "+rows[i].artist_id + rowDelimiter;
```

Comment: @GleneaMan, hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of leaving a comment saying "Thanks"  you should accept or up-vote helpful answers. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment